# Eclipse Operations has been very slow after importing a very big project

Tags: java, eclipse

I have imported a very big java  project from CVS .
The problem is that , since it is being a very big project , The Eclipse Operations like clean , run , copy --etc has been very slow .
Could you please let me know , how can we resolve this ??

Comment: If it's a monolithic project where you can't close any subprojects: better hardware?! Starting with a SSD.

Comment: What did you do to resolve your issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Task Manager to identify if Eclipse is swapping.  If swapping add more memory.

If not swapping, increase amount of memory available to Eclipse: http://blog.xam.dk/?p=58

If hitting the ceiling of a 32-bit JVM (around 3 GB) upgrade to 64-bit.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Windows, change your shortcut target to: C:\\eclipse.exe -vmargs -Xms512m -Xmx1024m

More details: http://blog.xam.dk/?p=58

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse maintains indexes over your code. These can use significant memory and IO resources.

Your biggest win after increasing heap size mentioned by others is to ensure that nothing is on a network drive.

- workspace,
- JDK
- eclipse installation

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot update your platform as suggested by others, then consider looking at the various label decorators. Especial the team specific decorators are known to be very expensive in large projects.

Look at your Preferences: "Team"->"CVS"->"Label Decorations". Clear "Compute deep...". (At least Mercurial and Git have the same preferences, though with different names. I haven't found a way to disable this in SVN.)

You might also want to have a general look at all the computed label decorators in "General"->"Appearance"->"Label Decorations". Depending on the installed features, there can be many that can be disabled with various performance gains...